# Sum of elements in JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following json 5 times in my database, and I need to calculate the sum of `no_of_steps` corresponding to every `asanas_id`. I.e the same json will loop for 5 times and i need total of `no_of_steps` for corresponding `asanas_id`.

`{"yoga_prescription":[{"result":[{"asanas_sub_category_id":"7","asanas_id":"5","no_of_step":"45","ratio":"5"},{"asanas_sub_category_id":"8","asanas_id":"7","no_of_step":"5","ratio":"5"}],"asanas_category_id":"1"},{"result":[{"asanas_sub_category_id":"11","asanas_id":"13","no_of_step":"54","ratio":"55"}],"asanas_category_id":"2"},{"result":[{"asanas_sub_category_id":"15","asanas_id":"17","no_of_step":"5","ratio":"5"}],"asanas_category_id":"3"}]}`

Comment: JSON is just data. It doesn't loop. What are you actually coding in?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, i have five instances for same json data stored in mysql database, and i want sum of "no_of_steps" form all the 5 entries.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for SQL. There is *no* indication of that in your question. Why are you storing JSON in your database anyway, rather than storing appropriate fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about what you are asking, but if you have always the same structure in your JSON you can loop the array inside `yoga_prescription`

It would be useful if you give more information. Which programming language are you using?

i.e. If you are using javascript:

```
function sumJson (jsonVar) {
var jsonLength = jsonVar.yoga_prescription.length;
var jTotal = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
    var resultLength = JSONVAR.yoga_prescription[i].result.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < resultLength; j++) {
        jTotal += parseInt(JSONVAR.yoga_prescription[i].result[j].no_of_step);
    }
}
return jTotal;
}
```

A working example here: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xazhkmo1/2/)